# Flutter does not make the Navigator

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a flutter app that receives notifications from Firebase Cloud Messaging, and I'm trying to make a certain screen open in the app, according to the notification date, this is my code:

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(
  (RemoteMessage message) {
    print("Data: ${message.data}");
    if (message.data['title'] == 'dash') {
      print('Data title test: ${message.data['title']}');
        Navigator.pop(context);
        Navigator.of(context).push(
            PageRouteBuilder(pageBuilder: (BuildContext context, _, __) {
          return Dashboard();
        }));
        Navigator.pop(context);
    } else {
      print('else');
    }
  },
);
```

This is the error I get on the console:

```
I/flutter (x): Data: {title: dash, message: mensagem 123}
I/flutter (x): Data title test: dash
E/flutter (x): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: This widget has been unmounted, so the State no longer has a context (and should be considered defunct).
E/flutter (x): Consider canceling any active work during "dispose" or using the "mounted" getter to determine if the State is still active.
```

Comment: You pass same `BuildContext` to your Navigator. BuildContext represents mounted widget, at first call you dispose of it with call `Navigator.of(context).pop`, but then next call `Navigator.of(context).push` forcing app to use invalid context that is not exist anymore, and thus have this error.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are popping `Dashboard` page just after pushing it!